# Implementing _leftChild and _rightChild into the deleteMax function of a Max Binary Heap Class

Tags: python, minmax-heap

I have the task of making a Max Binary Heap class and I have made functions to find the left and right child. I have also made a function deleteMax that deletes the max number in the heap and sorts accordingly, But I made it without calling the first two functions and am not sure how to change the code accordingly.

```
class MaxBinaryHeap:
  
    def __init__(self):
        self._heap=[]
        
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self._heap}'

    __repr__=__str__

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._heap)
    
    @property
    def getMax(self):
        if len(self) == 0:
            return None
        else:
            return self._heap[0]
        
    
    def _parent(self,index):
        if index <= 1 or index > len(self): 
            return None
        else: 
            return self._heap[(index // 2)-1]
        

    def _leftChild(self,index):
        if 2*index < len(self): 
            return self._heap[(2 * index) - 1]
        else:
            return None


    def _rightChild(self,index):
        if (2*index) - 1 < len(self): 
            return self._heap[(2 * index)]
        else:
            return None
         

    def insert(self,x):
        self._heap.append(x)
        current = len(self._heap) - 1
        while self._parent(current + 1) is not None and self._heap[current] > self._parent(current + 1):
            parent_current = ((current + 1) // 2) -1
            self._heap[current], self._heap[parent_current] = self._heap[parent_current], self._heap[current]
            current = parent_current
           
        

    def deleteMax(self):
        if len(self) == 0:
            return None
        elif len(self) == 1:
            removed = self._heap[0]
            self._heap = []
            return removed

        max_value = self._heap[0]

        last_value = self._heap.pop()
        self._heap[0] = last_value

        
        current = 0
        left_child_index = 2 * current + 1
        right_child_index = 2 * current + 2

        while left_child_index < len(self._heap):
            swap_index = left_child_index
            if (right_child_index < len(self._heap) and self._heap[right_child_index] > self._heap[left_child_index]):
                swap_index = right_child_index

            if self._heap[swap_index] > self._heap[current]:
                self._heap[current], self._heap[swap_index] = self._heap[swap_index], self._heap[current]

            current = swap_index
            left_child_index = 2 * current + 1
            right_child_index = 2 * current + 2

        return max_value
```

Comment: first of all, the indentation looks incorrect for the `_rightChild()` function...

Comment: secondly, it looks like these methods belong in a `class`. . .

Comment: Its right in the code but when I submitted the question it indented.

Comment: okay,  you need to fix this. python requires indentation and the function looks like a nested function with the indentation.

Comment: I put the whole code for less confusion

Answer (score 0):

thanks for posting the whole code, which makes it clear...

if you want to call a method inside a class, all you have to do is this:

```py
left_child_index = self._leftChild(index=100)
```

in the example above, the return value of the `_leftChild()` method is assigned to `left_child_index` variable.

It is up to you where to uses these (if you need to).

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am not allowed to use any list methods, so index wouldn't be allowed. Thank you for the example and explanation tho

Comment: `index` is just a variable in the method in the original question. it is not a list.